# Ubuntu Server 12.04: can't write to nfs share

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, nfs

I have installed a small home server running 12.04, now trying to configure an NFS share with Webmin version 1.620. I have gradually lowered the security on the share to basically nil, yet any write operation to the share from any MAC OS X or Windows 7 (with NFSClient 1.7) is consistently rejected. The NFS Client on Windows e.g. returns "Permission denied" (along with lots of cryptic stuff) when trying to create a new directory, or when dropping a file.

Any hint on the matter?

Thanks a lot & best regards
Mark

Comment: "along with lots of cryptic stuff" cryptic to you does not mean cryptic to us. Heck, it might be what we need to provide you with a good answer so ... please add ite to your question (do watch out to not to copy passwords ;) ) Thing is... your question probably is related to permissions so set them correctly and you do not get errors ;)

Comment: Please share the command with which you mounted the NFS share.

Comment: Valid point ... when trying to create a new folder on the remote 12.04 with the NFSClient on Win 7 I get the following message:

Comment: NFSLibrary.Protocols.Commons.Exceptions.NFSAuthenticationException:
Permission denied. The caller does not have the correct permission to perform
the requested operation. Contrast this with NFS3ERR_PERM, which restricts itself
to owner or privileged user permission failures.
 bei
NFSLibrary.Protocols.Commons.Exceptions.ExceptionHelpers.ThrowException(NF
SStats ErrorCode]
 bei NFSLibrary.Protocols.V3.NFSv3.CreateDirectory(String DirectorFullName,
NFSPermission Mode)
 bei NFSLibrary.NFSClient.CreateDirectory(String DirectoryFullName,
NFSPermission Mode)

Comment: bei NFSClient.MainForm.btnNewFolder_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: I have a couple of screenshots but apparently one cannot upload them here.

Comment: Rinzwind, indeed, permission problem: chmod 777 on one of the  sub-directories fixed the issue. Thanks guys! /M.